# form goes out of control when adding action="" in laravel

Tags: php, html, css, forms, laravel

im trying to buld a complate form using laravel but i cant make this right :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

      {{Form::open(array('url'=>'register'))}}
```

but clearly this does not do anything with my data base so i want this :

```
<form  class="form-horizontal" action={{ url('our/target/route') }}" method="post">
```

but when i do this my form is not horizontal anymore and becomes something un watchable

so what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you have two `<form>`

Try this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
    <fieldset>
```